# Align image angle with a skew div

Tags: html, css

I have an background image that has an angle inside (the red circle and white angle in the snippet below)

I want to align the skewed gray div with the white line.
I can get them to align but when i resize the browser they separate.
How do i make the gray div to align with that white angle always no matter what the browser size is?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
.angle-circle {
  background: url('http://mototype.com/pics/4720/small/ducati_circle_d_logo.jpg') top right no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 200;
}
.gray-div {
  transform: skewX(168deg);
  background: #ccc;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  right: -28%;
  z-index: 100;
  /* what to do here to align to the red angle */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="angle-circle"></div>
  <div class="gray-div"></div>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries,
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries,
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries,
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You could provide a more tidy/detailed question. Why do you need it? What the role of this "set", is layout, is content? Also, your snippet isn't working... I don't downvoted your question, but understand whom did it...

Comment: i don't understand why it was down-voted because that is all the details i can give due to confidentiality of the project. Also, the snippet is an example because the real code is quite large and confidential

Comment: You can specify if it's for layout, of if you want to display a content in that way, or even a generic description and I still will cannot stole your project even if I want.
I ask about more details because your question is non usual, abstract, and also when you know exactly what is the problem, you can think in a better/other way to solve it...
I guess your question was downvoted because it's vague/foggy, and does not show much effort. Your snippet doesn't even works!

Comment: i see now that it is kind of vague. I've edited my snippet to illustrate what i meant. if you open it in full page and resize the browser, you'll see that the gray div angle is not sticking to the angle inside the circle.

Comment: Don't be afraid about be to much secret, principally if is Html/CSS. If you are a WebDeveloper, you are exposed to the World Wide Web. Once the client receives a response of your Html/CSS, there will be no secrets for anyone...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give a shoot in the darkness (because I barely understood your question), but resizing the browser changing the position of absolute object sounds two things:

1 - You don't give a parent with position relative for your absolute positioned divs/elements. Thus, it get's the window as reference.

2 - You are using some percentage unit for parents or other place not shown. Thus, changing the browser window, changes the distances...

Please provide how much details as possible, and also, a jsfiddle or working snippet helps a lot for Us whom want to help you! :)

**Update:**
http://jsfiddle.net/d2xuf7qm/1/

The trick is: All the widths of your elements are percentage based, but the image it not. So the distance that the circle must to have from right is relative because the width of gray div is relative. But the main problem is that you have a fixed width to the circle, so how the circle will know how much it needs to come over the div since it is dynamic? With a negative `margin-right` :)

First I aligned both elements percentages, so they can move, and still side by side. Then with margin-right negative I tell how much in pixels the angle start, thus, aligning the circle with div.

Comment: 1. container does have position relative
2. i've added more to the snippet to illustrate.
thanks!

Comment: Ok, now I understood. You problem is the second I described. You are using percentage to locate a image (that is a fixed bitmap). Change the width and things will not match anymore.

Comment: yes, exactly. i need that gray div to align with the angle line inside the image no matter what the browser width is.

Comment: Do you want to resize this circle?

Comment: no, i cannot resize the circle due to branding issue.

Comment: Ok, I think I can make something... Just a second

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69424/discussion-between-newbie-dev-and-vitox).